# MYSTERY IN C++: Function call misbehaving just because of the presence of another function call even though they are unrelated

Tags: c++, file, stream, fstream

My program searches for a string in a file, return the line number and then copy all lines of the file just before the line number of the searched string, into another file. But to my greatest suprise, which I regard as a MYSTERY, is that;

1. when the searched string line number is passed to the file copy function, instead of copying all lines before the searched string line number as defined in the file copy function, it does the reverse
2. if i change to greater than in the file copy function i.e. such that it should copy all lines after the searched string line number, nothing is copied at all.
3. if instead i manually enter a line number in the file copy function i.e. not using the search string line number returned, same thing happens as in 1 and 2 above.
4. finally, if i remove the search string function and manually enter a line number into the copy file function, everything works fine in both direction i.e for copying lines before or after the line number.
   Really, this is a MYSTERY. PLEASE WHO CAN HELP?

HERE IS THE PROGRAM

```
#include <fstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>
    #include <string>

std::ifstream fin;
std::ofstream fout;
void Copyfile(std::ifstream& in_stream, std::ofstream& out_stream, std::string Line,int searchstringline);
int searchString(std::ifstream& in_stream, std::string string1);

int main(){

    fin.open("C++.txt");
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Output file opening failed.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    fout.open("Temp.txt",std::ios::app);
    if (fin.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "Input file opening failed.\n";
        fin.close();
        exit(1);
    }

    int searchstringline;
    searchstringline = searchString(fin, "main");
    Copyfile(fin, fout, "line", searchstringline);



}



void Copyfile(std::ifstream& in_stream, std::ofstream& out_stream, std::string Line, int searchstringline){
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; getline(fin,Line); i++){
        count++;
        while (count < searchstringline){
            out_stream << Line << std::endl;
            break;
        }

    }


}

int searchString(std::ifstream& in_stream, std::string string1){
    std::string input;
    int number = 0;
    for (int i = 0; getline(fin, input); i++){
        number++;
        if (input.find(string1) != std::string::npos){

            break;
        }

    }
    return number;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: Those functions are not unrelated. They take modifiable references to the same object (`fin`) and modify what they're given.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious, I was contesting the OP's statement. The OP stated that they are unrelated and I explicitly said that this was a false statement by adding a layer of negation.

Comment: Warning: testing `fin`, not `fout`, for failure after `fout.open`.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to the mystery is simply closing the file after calling the searchstring function and reopening it before calling the copyfile function. This is advisable generally whenever you have more than one function accessing a file in order to avoid distortion due to a function reflecting after another function is called to use the file.
 Cheers!